# How to change the color of UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I want to change the color of `UINavigationBar`, color will be taken from an image.

Comment: You wanrt change color or use image

Comment: i want to change the background of UINavigationBar, i am using colorWithImagePattern , but its not working

Answer (score 6):

try to set the objects as subviews to the navigationBar.

Set the tint color property or use images

```
UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController]; 
controller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 7 or later, try the following:

```
navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are supporting only iOS5 and later, you can use "appearance proxy". There is [a good tutorial for this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5).

If you have to support prior versions, you have to subclass `UINavigationBar` and override its `drawRect` method. There is [a good sample code for this](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/CustomBackButton).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. First create the Objective C class say `CustomNavBar` inherited `UINavigationBar` class...
2. then import this class in your appDelegate...
3. then Place this below code at the end of you appDelegate class...
4. then open your `MainWindow.xib` and change the `UINavigationBar class to`CustomNavBar`.

The code:

```
@implementation CustomNavBar (CustomNavBarCategory)

-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx 
{

    if([self isMemberOfClass:[CustomNavBar class]])
    {
        UIImage *image;

        image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName"];

        CGContextClip(ctx);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, image.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx,CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), image.CGImage); 

    }
    else 
    {        
        [super.layer drawLayer:layer inContext:ctx];     
    }

}  

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this from storyboard in xcode 6.4.

From the document outline select Navigation bar
[image]

Than from attribute inspector change bar tint
[image]

You can also pick other and this will bring the color picker 
[image]

Pick the dropper and this will let you pick a color from an image
[image]