# UINavigationBar change tint color in Category

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I know I can change the tint color of navigation bar in xib file easily. But the problem is that if i have to change in a lot of places.

Hence i tried using the (fancy) category and overriding the draw rect method.

```
#import "UINavigationBar+customTint.h"

@implementation UINavigationBar (customTint)

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    self.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

@end
```

I have imported it in the corresponding view controller as well. What am i doing wrong?
Whats the right way of doing it?

THanks in advance

Comment: see this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206116/how-to-i-change-the-color-of-uinavigationbar/9206204#9206204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is one way of doing it. It would probably just be easier in you `ViewController` where ever you need to change it add the line:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Using a category for just one line is probably overkill.

EDIT:
If you do want to use a category, you may need to call `setNeedsDisplay` on the navigation bar. or override another method and call it.
Something like ,

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];
```

> [Also according to Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_0/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010949-CH1-SW29)
>
> In iOS 5, the UINavigationBar, UIToolbar, and UITabBar implementations have changed so that the drawRect: method is not called unless it is implemented in a subclass. Apps that have re-implemented drawRect: in a category on any of these classes will find that the drawRect: method isn't called. UIKit does link-checking to keep the method from being called in apps linked before iOS 5 but does not support this design on iOS 5 or later. 
>   Apps can either:
>
> - Use the customization API for bars in iOS 5 and later, which is the preferred way.
> - Subclass UINavigationBar (or the other bar classes) and override drawRect: in the subclass.

The best way to therefore go about this would be to place this in your `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching`

```
NSString *reqSysVer = @"5.0";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:myColor];
```

And also leave your `DrawRect`, so that it will work on iOS less than 5

Comment: Consider I have to change at 3 different places and when everything is done, the graphic designer asks me to change it. Then i have to change in 3 places again.

Comment: Doesn't matter, You can put this code in 3 different places, or as many times as you want. Just change the color to what you want.

Comment: my question is how to change it in one common place?

Comment: Note that overriding drawRect: may have performance implications.

Comment: "Then I have to change in 3 places again." One approach is to put all this sort of global stuff in #defines, in a single file (e.g. "constants.h") that you #import from every viewcontroller file, then you only need to change it in one place.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using iOS5 then the correct way to do it is to use the UIAppearance proxy.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:myColor];
```

Details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This is only needed once and will affect all UINavigationBars, you can call this from applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Comment: but thats only for iOS 5? How about for previous iOS versions

Comment: Same as @Amit Shah's answer - you have to iterate through all UINavigationBars.  One way you could do it is to create a Singleton which returns your preferred tint color, and use that when you initialize the UINavigationBar - then you only have to change it in once place when the designer decides that he needs 1% more Red, or found a new page in the Pantone catalogue...